# how do you write gcAllowVeryLargeObjects using codebehind

Tags: c#, gcallowverylargeobjects

how do I write this in c# in the code behind? gcAllowVeryLargeObjects   I can't use a config file.

below is the config files version

```
   <configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It needs to be up front.  In the .config file, it configures the CLR before it starts.  You can therefore not write anything similar in C#.  If you can't change the .config file then that's the end of it.  Which is surely for the better.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, because this configures how the runtime operates. You cannot modify how the runtime's garbage collector operates *while the runtime is executing*. You must do it *before* the runtime, thus the configuration requirement.